# How to find/download latest drupal version via bash?

Tags: files

I'm trying to pull up the latest Drupal release, and download it via a bash script.

I don't have any idea on how I can do that, except that I found out I can list the files on the FTP server, and get all the filenames containing Drupal, like so:

```
lynx --dump http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/ | awk '/http/{print $2}' | grep drupal-7 > latest.txt
```

How I can pull the latest version from that list, and download it?

Comment: Some HTTP and FTP clients can download the newest file matching a wildcard if you point them to a directory. IIRC Curl has this functionality.

Comment: You could use `sort` with version sort option i.e. `sort -V`. Assuming you don't want dev, alpha or beta (untested): `lynx --dump http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/ | awk '/http/{print $2}' | grep drupal-7 |sort -V |grep -v dev|grep -v alpha|grep -v beta|tail -n 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command will do it.

```bsh
wget  http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/$(wget -O- http://drupal.org/project/drupal | egrep -o 'drupal-[0-9\.]+.tar.gz' | sort -V  | tail -1)
```

Here goes the explanation.

```bsh
wget -O- http://drupal.org/project/drupal |  # <- Download drupal main download site
    egrep -o 'drupal-[0-9\.]+.tar.gz' | # <- searching drupal-[0-9\.]+.tar.gz pattern
                                        # Also only showing the matched pattern
    sort -V  |  # <- sort it by version number (default sort order is ascending) 
    tail -1  | grab the last name which would be highest version
```

After this we get something like `drupal-7.12.tar.gz` or `drupal-7.12.zip`. Then it gets replaced in the final `wget` invocation.

```bsh
wget  http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.12.tar.gz
```

Comment: That will fail in many cases unless you are using a version of sort that supports --version-sort (and use that option).

Comment: Yeah. I was experimenting on console. Updated already.

Comment: Actually this one worked, but unfortunately I cant seem to understand the sorting thing with egrep, seems a bit tricky for me. Thanks indeed.

Comment: @AltinUkshini answer is updated with explanation. Check again.

Comment: Aha now I get it. I was confused at 0-9\. now I see that it means from 0 to 9 :) . Thank ou so much again :D

Answer (score 8):

For all your command line and script needs there is [Drush](https://drupal.org/project/drush). To download the latest Drupal 7 with it, you simply do

```
drush pm-download drupal
```

Answer (score 1):

If GNU grep is available and GET from perl's libwww, you can use the following, but it will fail if the format of their project page ever changes:

```
wget $(GET http://drupal.org/project/drupal | grep -Po '(?<=<a href=")http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7[.]\d{1,2}[.]tar[.]gz(?=">tar.gz)')
```

Comment: Im getting an error at this one:

Comment: grep: Support for the -P option is not compiled into this --disable-perl-regexp binary
wget: missing URL
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Comment: @AltinUkshini What version of Linux are you using that doesn't have -P support for grep?

Answer (score 1):

The currently accepted answer no longer works after the update to the Drupal website.

This method utilizes the update XML and should hopefully be more reliable.

As stated in other answers, the best option is to use drush, but if that is not an option then this should do:

```
wget $(wget -O- -q https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/7.x | grep -oPm1 "(?<=<download_link>)[^<]+" | head -1)
```

Credit to this stackoverflow answer for the XML extraction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17333829/2383249

Comment: It downloads all the version. I only want the latest one, how do I do that.

Comment: I just updated the code so that there is a | head -1 after the grep statement so it only retrieves the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

I know @Shiplu's answer works best for OP, but just to add a comment; sometimes you may find it convenient to ask Apache which is the newest file:

```
$ wget 'http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/?C=M;O=A' -O- | egrep -o 'drupal-[0-9\.]+\.zip' | tail -1
(snip)
drupal-7.12.zip
```

The above URL was copied from the link labelled as "Last Modified".  See also

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_autoindex.html#query

Comment: Last modified could be a 6.0 or dev version.

Answer (score 0):

If you can install (and don't mind installing) the nokogiri cli (e.g. `sudo apt-get install ruby-nokogiri` on ubuntu), you could do the following

```
nokogiri https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/7.x -e 'print @doc.at_xpath("//download_link/text()")'
```

which outputs

```
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/7.50
```